# Modify Partitions of USB on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, usb, partitioning

In Disk Manager we see the USB drive ..

[image]

but its partitioning settings are not coming up as modifiable:

[image]

My intention is to generate a UEFI bootable usb .. but that requires access to the partition info on the USB. What step(s) am I missing here?

Comment: What kind of USB? USB harddisk, USB flashdrive, USB connected phone? USB printer? If it is an USB flash drive / USB pen drive then you might run into a 'challenge' because windows 7 (and I assume also windows 8 and 8.1) treat those special and only work with one partition  on them.

Comment: Also, you could just use the command line (`diskpart` `select disk X` `clean` `convert GPT `create partition primary fs=fat32` IIRC)

Comment: @Hennes it's the the removable medium bit (RMB) in its SCSI INQUIRY data. If RMB=1, Disk Management shows "Removable" and allows only one partition; if RMB=0, it shows "Basic" and allows multiple partitions.